# c++ libcurl - use the response from previous curl as parameter to another curl

Tags: c++, json, libcurl

I am using C++ libcurl to POST data to a webservice and everything works fine. I would like to use the webservice response (Json) as parameter to a make another POST in another webservice. Can you guys help me? Thank you very much

```
//FIRST POST
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url1.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postData.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpResponse1(new std::string());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpResponse1.get());
curl_easy_perform(curl);

//SECOND POST
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url2.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, httpResponse1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
std::unique_ptr<std::string> httpResponse2(new std::string());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, httpResponse2.get());
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend reading and basing such work on the public libcurl examples that have what you need:

1. Receive in memory: [getinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)
2. POST from memory (and receive that response too in memory): [postinmemory.c](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/postinmemory.html)

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for replaying. 
The problem is not storing the response in memory... I am already using callback functions and storing the received data. The problem is the received data is not in the correct format to send it again.

Comment: You're in total control of the data once it is received. Then convert it however you see fit so that it gets in the correct syntax to send. Then send it!

Comment: This is the problem, I don't know how to manipulate the data to fit in the libcurl POSTFIELD format. I am using JsonCpp lib but it is not working. Do you have any tip ?

Comment: curl sends the POSTFIELD data exactly as-is, you point it to a buffer of bytes and those bytes are what libcurl will send!

Comment: this is what I am doing (you can see in the code), even if I use the & sign to point to the array of bytes, I receive only memory garbage in the server side.

Comment: No, you pass in a C++ string object there, which is not the same thing.

Comment: You are right... Now I am trying to use the WriteData from the example but it is not working on C++ compiler. I think it works only in C.

Comment: Had to make a cast in the Malloc, but worked!! Thank you very much Daniel